# Loading-Page for angular resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularjs with ui-router.

I would like to use the resolve-object to load some async stuff and only display the final page when everything is loaded..

this works fine but how can I display a "loading" page to the user?

```
 $stateProvider
        .state(model.constants.RouteStates.MAIN, {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "modules/main.html",
            controller: "mainctrl",
            controllerAs: "currentCtrl",
            resolve: {
                app: function($q) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    //do some asyc stuff...

                    //display a "please-wait"-page for the user while requesting asyc-stuff...

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
         }
```

Comment: I think you can do that listening to $stateChangeStart in your controller, because your state will only change when your resolve as ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.name="your_resolve_state") {
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
    }
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.name="your_resolve_state") {
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
    }
});
```

or after your resolve has finished in your controller you can call

```
$scope.showSpinner = false;
```

in the beginning

Comment: that looks nice. Can you show me an implementation of your "showSpinner"-method? I don't know how to display content on the page because we don't have the controller yet, right? And I'm using the controllerAs-object to get an instance of a controller

Comment: You can implement show spinner, just putting a variable to true, and use an ng-show in your html with that variable. I've edited my answer it's simpler. You can just put the $scope.showSpinner in an ng-show in the element with your spinner

Comment: In one of my apps I did it in a diferent way, I put a element in front of the main page that filled the entire screen with a spinner. 
Then in the controller I did the async stuff, when finished I would hide the element in front and show the page in the back. It's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I used another way to show a loading-page.

I have a global-variable with a promise which will fire when the global intializiation has finished.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
mymodule.globalVars.PromiseInit = deferred.promise;
```

In my constructor (I'm using typescript) I can just say

```
export class Test
{

    initialized: boolean = false;

    constructor()
    {
        mymodule.globalVars.PromiseInit.then(()=>{
            //everything global is loaded so I can start with my controller-stuff
             this.initialized=true;
        })

    }

    isInitialized(){
        return this.initialized;
    }
```

on my html-page i used the following:

```
<div ng-show="!currentCtrl.isInitialized()">
    <div ng-include="'modules/_wait.html'"></div><!--this is my loading-spinner -->
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="currentCtrl.isInitialized()">
...
```

the method isInitialized just checks an property which I set when everything is loaded.